# df. drop results in unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'bool'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I want to remove rows with below condition but I faced with below error:
How can we remove rows with 2 conditions with different cariable type?

```
result['LastDigit']= result['IP'].str.strip().str[-1].astype(int)

result = result.drop(result[result['Type']=='A'] & result[result['LastDigit'] %2 ==0], axis=1)
```

ERROR:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'bool'
```

Sample:

```
    UniqueCode  ID     IP_Address       Name    Type LastDigit
0      QQ       22     172.16.1.67      Name1     A     7
2      XX       33     172.2.12.68      Name2     A     8
4      ZZ       44     10.21.22.2       Name3     B     2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with inverted original mask by `~` and also add `()` because priority of operators:

```
result = result[~((result['Type']=='A') & (result['LastDigit'] %2 ==0))]
```

Or invert masks for test not equal with `|` for bitwise `OR`:

```
result = result[(result['Type']!='A') | (result['LastDigit'] %2 !=0)]
print (result)
  UniqueCode  ID   IP_Address   Name Type  LastDigit
0         QQ  22  172.16.1.67  Name1    A          7
4         ZZ  44   10.21.22.2  Name3    B          2
```

Comment: I add the code but nothing happened. However have multiple rows wiith mentioned conditions.

Comment: @SaraDaniel - Is possible add some sample data like 2-5 rows for test solution?

Comment: Sure it has been shared.

Comment: @SaraDaniel - For me working well, just added to answer.

Comment: It was my fault. Many Thanks. It works properly.